# Creating Threads results in force close in android app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a thread to handle a login function that is executed when the login button is pushed, so that I can show a progressDialog.

```
   btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check Login


            ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this, "", "Loading...");
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        int duration;
                        Toast toast;
                        Context context;
                        String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                        JSONArray jsonArray=null;
                        password=ServerConnection.encryptPassword(password);
                        //Log.i("login hash",password);
                        jsonArray=ServerConnection.login(username, password);

                        if(jsonArray!=null) //login successful
                        {
                            context=getApplicationContext();
                            duration=Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            toast=Toast.makeText(context, "Login Successful!", duration);
                            toast.show();//Shows the little pop up right at the bottom of the screen
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapWithFriends.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            context=getApplicationContext();
                            duration=Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            toast=Toast.makeText(context, "Login Fail", duration);
                            toast.show();//Shows the little pop up right at the bottom of the screen
                            //lblResult.setText("Login failed. Username and/or password doesn't match.");
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }).start();


        }
    });
```

However when the thread is created, it force closes. If I change back to no threads, it works fine.

Thanks

Edit: 
LogCat of crash:
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
java.lang.NullPointerException 
.....
would you guys need more than this?

Comment: Give us the crash stack trace, we're not magicians. :)

Comment: Oh sorry, adding it now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't modify the UI from any thread except the main thread <strike>, as you do in: `progressDialog.dismiss();`</strike>

Consider using [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead. And I would also recommend reading [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html).

Comment: Actually [`dismiss`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29) is safe to run from any thread. But you're right, and the issue probably lies with all the `Toast` code

Comment: @Craigy - I was not aware of that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Craigy, I tried commenting out the toast and still force closes. Thank you though

Comment: Thanks, I got the AsyncTask working. However it would crash if I use toast. How do you recommend I alert the user that their login information is invalid?

Comment: Should have googled it lol. I am now trying the alert dialogs :D Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

From a non-UI thread use something like

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  // Your UI modifications here
});
```

or

```
yourUIControl.post(new Runnable() {
   // something like
   yourUIControl.setText("new text");
});
```